# My Android App is working on the emulator but not on the android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I'm running my android application on the emulator (version 2.2) and it works fine.
However, when I try the application on my android device (version 4.1) it doesn't work. I get errors in the log as follows:

```
12-27 16:54:22.080: E/Trace(25485): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #73: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5696)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5832)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1099)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:956)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:70)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.newView(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:104)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at example.smartdialup.PhoneSpellDialer$ContactListAdapter.newView(PhoneSpellDialer.java:720)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:246)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2457)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1614)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2292)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4602)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4602)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4602)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4602)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4602)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1990)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1811)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1110)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4470)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-27 16:54:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(25485):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.smartdialup"
   android:versionName="1.81" android:versionCode="14">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PhoneSpellDialer"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:theme="@style/Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Preferences"></activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!--  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"></uses-sdk>-->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true" />
</manifest>
```

Do you have any idea how to run the application successfully on my device?

Comment: You are missing Layout Width attribute in your XMl add that to your XML file and then check

Comment: This wouldn't work on an emulator either.   Your code has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as log says :

> Binary XML file line #73: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

means you forget to add  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`  in Xml layout of your Activity for View.

Comment: I have many xml files, how do I know which one to edit?
Thanks,

Comment: @ÐinaYŏŜri : in PhoneSpellDialer Activity layout and xml which you are using for listview row

Answer (score 0):

Your custom list item view defined in your `newView(...)` is missing a `android:layout_width` attribute it seems. Need to always be set (along with the layout_height attribute) to either `fill_parent` or `wrap_content`

Have a look at the xml layout file you are inflating in your code: `example.smartdialup.PhoneSpellDialer$ContactListAdapter.newView(PhoneSpellDialer.java:720)`

A `RelativLayout` there or one if it's sub views probably.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty strange you get that 'difference' between the emulator and your real device, because that error should also occur on your emulator. That's one of the reasons why I develop in both the emulator and a real device, behavior between both differs more than you like.

XML file line #73: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

This error is quite straight forward, every element you add to the layout XML ought to have an layout_width and layout_height so Android knows how to display them.

You haven't supplied the layout XML so I can't show you a corrected one. One example from my layout's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the layout_width and layout_height are being used in all 'XML tags' so Android knows how to position them.

match_parent is one of the values, which one you need can be found on the Android-developer site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#layoutvalues

Tip: You're using Eclipse for developing with Android? type in: android:layout_width=" and then press CTRL+SPACEBAR it should autocomplete ;)

Comment: WORKED Finally .. 
Thanks,